# KineticJS images not working locally, sometimes work online

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, kineticjs

I'm testing KineticJS right now. I tried adding an image to the canvas following this [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-image-tutorial/). I changed a bit the code but it's relatively the same.

What's confusing is that locally it's not working at all...no images are displayed and no errors at all. Online is a different story, images are loaded BUT sometimes it looks like the images are not loading.

This is what I have: http://codepen.io/semajtwin/pen/nIafc

I thought maybe it was the browser as well, I tried on three different browsers (Chrome, Firefox and Internet explorer) but still ended up with the same result.

I just can't figure out what's wrong really.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should show the image when it is loaded: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LircJ)

Comment: @RobinvdA thanks a lot for your comment!! That definitely did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@RobinvdA is correct that you need to give the images time to load.**

Your draw `draw_img();` and `draw_img2();` are being called before the images are fully loaded.

The fix is to put the draw_img code inside onload, like this:

Here's some refactored code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fLPZt/

```
// declare sun_img outside `onload` so it's accessible later

var sun_img;

// create a Kinetic.Image of the sun

var sunReady = false;
var sunImage = new Image();
sunImage.onload = function () {
    sun_img = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        image: sunImage,
        draggable: true
    });
    layer.add(sun_img);
    layer.draw();
};
sunImage.src = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-GDMbp9j3iSo/Tgh24-ighVI/AAAAAAAAAgE/a4glfYd5-68/s200/radiantsunheliumballoon.jpg";
```

Comment: Yep, @RobinvdA is right. Thanks for your help as well Mark.